# Producing curves with varying size to connect points in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve

**Problem:**

I want to connect points with curves, while the curve size adjusts along its path according to the size of its respective end points.

**Reproducible example:**

```
library("tidyverse")
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,2),
             y=c(1,4,3),
             value=c(2,10,15),
             order=c(1,2,3))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,
                 y=y,
                 size=value),
             alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

So far, so good. Now I would like to add curves connecting the points, according to the following rules:

1. The curves are supposed to link the points chronologically 1 -- 2 -- 3 (according to the `df$order` that is)
2. End point sizes that were created via `aes(size=value)` determine respective curve sizes.
3. Curve size increases/decreases in a nice, smoothed way.

What I would like to achieve is more or less this (sorry for my horrible MS paint skills...infortunately rule 3 gets violated in this sketch...):

[image]

It would also be nice to be able to pass `aes()` to the curves, such as `colour`...I've been playing around with `geom_curve` and `geom_segment`, but I didnt get very far...

The whole exercise serves to reproduce [this](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/4b/db/aa/4bdbaac5deb2b4fbb70e32662de3d1ac--a-magazine-transfer.jpg) amazing infographic.

Comment: A few comments on your ideas.  1) If you have enough points, you can use geom_path() to connect the points using curve(segments). 2). The shape of curve will be misleading if you want it to smooth and adjusted by the size.

Comment: I'm super interested in this. You might want to check out `geom_link2` in the `ggforce` package, which is like `geom_path` but with a calculated index interpolated between points. You might also look into how you can do splines between your points, but I'm not sure how to make that work

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% 
  mutate( x1 = c(NA, x[1:(nrow(df)-1) ] )) %>% 
  mutate( x2 = c(NA, x[2:(nrow(df)) ]   )) %>% 
  mutate( y1 = c(NA, y[1:(nrow(df)-1) ] )) %>% 
  mutate( y2 = c(NA, y[2:(nrow(df)) ]   )) ->df

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y,size=value)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
  geom_curve(aes(x = x1, xend = x2, y = y1, yend = y2),
         curvature = .25, size = 1)
```

[image: geom_curve]

Comment: Good start, but not quite what I wanted. You fixed the size of the curve to 1. I want it to adjust to the point sizes of its ends.